# Can I upload multimedia from subscription access journals to third party websites

Tags: copyright

I am the author of an accepted and published manuscript in a peer-reviewed subscription access article. Accompanying this manuscript are some videos I created. I would like to upload these videos to a third party website and want to know if this is allowed. I have read the author rights, but my use doesn't exactly fit into the wording so I'm not so sure what the answer is.

More specifically my article is in 2D Materials of IOP and I want to upload some videos that form part of the additional multimedia to YouTube so that I can create an interactive poster where people can view videos related to content on the poster.

I have emailed the IOP concerning this matter so I can provide an answer to at least my specific case, but I thought others might have something interesting to say on this matter, e.g. perhaps the intended use means it automatically is "fair use" and is acceptable for all journals.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

After further emails and confusions settled, IOP was more than happy to grant me permissions to use the videos. One thing I discovered is that technically, even if you're just using one or two of the figures from your paper for a poster you should ask permission from IOP. I'm not sure how common this is.

**~~~~~~~~**

The email response to my specific case was:

"Under the copyright form, IOP Publishing only take a non-exclusive licence from you to use and publish the video abstract (clause 1.3). Therefore we do not control what you do with the video abstract. Please note, if you have used any third party material in your video, you may need to consider whether the permission you were granted was wide enough to use that content on YouTube."

One thing to note is she is talking about the video abstract and not video figures, but I'm personally going to say that's enough of a green light for me.